# Idea para Auditar eventos de aplicación web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Buenas a tod@s,

Esta es la primera vez que me pego con el tema de auditar eventos que suceden en una aplicación web, por lo que pido paciencia jejeje.

La aplicación en la que tengo que hacer auditoria está construida con **Spring Boot.** Hace uso de **Spring Security** y poco más.

Estuve mirando por Internet y todo lo que encontré creo no me vale pues yo necesito registrar todas las transacciones en una tabla propia con unos determinados campos... quiero decir, **Hibernate Envers** o S**pring Data JPA** (por ejemplo) crean unas tablas auxiliares de todas las entidades que anotemos y registra las propiedades de las entidades que así configuremos.

el proyecto está estructurado por capas, teniendo a mayor nivel los controladores, después los **Services, Repository** y por último los Bean del modelo.

Espero puedan ayudarme y si pueden aportar ejemplos se lo agradecería...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo mismo me contesto jejeje.

Para resolver el mi problema he usado la notación **@EntityListeners** de JPA.

En la clase "controladora" (desde ahora listener) debemos hacer uso de las notaciones **@PrePersist** (se ejecuta antes de hacer el insert), **@PreUpdtae**, **@PreRemove** etc...

Dejo link de explicación: https://programmingmitra.blogspot.com.es/2017/02/automatic-jpa-auditing-persisting-audit-logs-automatically-using-entityListeners.html

En las clases de persistencia tienes que decir con **@EntityListeners({*claseListener*.class})** la clase listener que controlará cualquier cambio que se de en dichas clases, siendo *claseListener* la clase donde hayamos anotado con @PreUpdate ...

Espero les sirva, 
 
Un saludo!!